# How to draw a walking route by two points Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, routes, cllocation, polyline

How would draw a walking route by two point (start and end). 
I wont use polyline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following tutorial [Draw Route Between two points](http://sugartin.info/2011/10/12/drawing-route-on-google-map-mkmapview/) Also Check [BreadCrumb example of Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010048-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) hope its helps to you!

You're not allowed to use google directions within your app. The only way you can do this is to send them to the google maps application as per:

```
- (void)getDirections {
CLLocationCoordinate2D start = { (startLatitude), (startLongitude) };
CLLocationCoordinate2D end = { (endLatitude), (endLongitude) };

NSString *googleMapsURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&daddr=%1.6f,%1.6f&dirflg=w", start.latitude, start.longitude, end.latitude, end.longitude];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:googleMapsURLString]];
```

}